# views filter's identifier

Tags: 7, views

I'm using drupal 7.

I want to use `$view->set_exposed_input(array('filter_identifier' => 'filter_value'));`

How to know the filter identifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the view exposed filter you can give it a name. You use the default name it gives you, or whatever you choose it to be. See attached image.

[image]